# edit a 2D XYZ Function?

Tags: mesh, mathematics, 2d

I'm a Blender newbie. This is my first approach and I am learning this program and how to use it in a more efficient way...any suggestion is very welcome!

Anyway, I am trying to draw a scientific figure. I want to draw a series of 4 pulses and I used the "XYZ math function" that allows me to write directly the mathematical formula for each pulse...However, now I'm not able to edit these pulses (like the color, thickness of the line...). How can I edit this line??

Probably this is a stupid question...but any tip is really appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is that you can convert this mesh of vertices in line into Curve like this here:

[image]

This way you will get your pulse as curve and you can go to Object data properties and use Geometry > Depth to give it some mass

[image]

if you want some points to be more thick, you can enlarge them by using Alt+S
[image]

If your curve will be to sharp, change resolution from 4 to something higher

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!